# Average DateDiff When FollowUpVisit column equals N

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's the code I've tried to no avail.

```
Select   
g.StopCodeName,
AVG(DateDiff(Day, DesiredAppointmentDate,AppointmentDateTime))Case When FollowUpVisitFlag = 'N' THEN  ELSE NULL END AS [AvgNewWt]
```

Note that I am trying group them by StopCode.  Please Help!!

Answer (score 0):

That's not a valid syntax in any DBMS. Move the `CASE` statement inside `AVG` aggregate

Try this way

```
SELECT g.StopCodeName,
       Avg(CASE
             WHEN FollowUpVisitFlag = 'N' THEN Datediff(Day, DesiredAppointmentDate, AppointmentDateTime)
             ELSE NULL
           END) AS [AvgNewWt]
```